# Python Openpyxl and download issues?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Trying to download from Excel into Python but Name of the columns do not appear
from the excel sheet. Also, I get a  second columns with all zeros. Below are the first two lines but it should have the columns names (data, close price, open price, etc)

**

```
import openpyxl
path="C:\Data\EXCELAMZNPY.xlsx"
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet=workbook.active #workbook.get_sheet_by_name("sheet1")
rows = sheet.max_row#1260
cols = sheet.max_column#7
print(rows)
print(cols)
for r in range(1,rows+1):
    for c in range(1,cols+1):
        print(sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value,end="    ")        
    
    print()
```

**

(NO COLUMN NAME BUT IT IS ON THE EXCEL SHEET!)
2016-02-18 00:00:00    541.19    541.2    523.73    525    4735008    AMZN
2016-02-19 00:00:00    520.71    535.95    515.35    534.9    4974717    AMZN

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try starting your ranges from 0.

Instead of this

```
for r in range(1,rows+1):
    for c in range(1,cols+1):
        print(sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value,end="    ")
```

try this

```
for r in range(0,rows):
        for c in range(0,cols):
            print(sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value,end="    ")
```